# Create table statement has an error in syntax for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, codeigniter

I'm trying to set up the CodeIgniter session table in my SQLite database, which is actually meant for MySQL.

I'm not that knowledgeable on SQLite syntax and I cannot find the error in this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: make sure the data types 'text' and 'unsigned' are supported.

Comment: I'm using phpLiteadmin and it's not really giving a meaningful error:  

There is a problem with the syntax of your query (Query was not executed)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` ( session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL, last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, user_data text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (session_id), KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`) )

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backticks from `ci_sessions` and other places. Backticks are not a portable way of escaping names, and they are not supported by SQLite.

Comment: I've added singles quotes, but it didn't work. I used sqlite studio to parse the query for me and it gives me this error: Error near "KEY": syntax error. If I remove that line, the query seems to work, but I'm unsure what consequences that has for Code Igniter.

Comment: Looks like the KEY syntax is wrong, then. Have a look at the SQLite documentation for foreign keys: http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: That's an option, but then I don't understand the KEY syntax of mySQL. When I search for it, it only gives me results for PRIMARY/FOREIGN KEY. So KEY in mySQL refers to FOREIGN KEY in SQLite?